# HBase mapr m7 python

Tags: python, hbase, mapr

I am new to HBase. I want to insert some data through python into HBase. I googled and found there is HappyBase api for HBase in Python but that, as per my understanding and findings, does not work with Mapr M7.

Please guide what package has to be imported in Python.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jarrettmeyer.com/2016/02/15/inserting-data-into-hbase-with-python

Comment: Thanks Whitefret for your reply...but in my question itself I have mentioned about HappyBase which your URL points to.

Comment: from what I see, to access HBase using python you either need HappyBase or the Thrift API. You can't work with java? If not, you can try and see jython maybe

Comment: @Ritesh Even Im trying same.. do you get any workaround to connect m7 tables using python?

Comment: @marjun I have a library called [pychbase](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pychbase) that can be used for m7/maprdb. Let me know if you need any assistance with it. I'll be rolling out a major update in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

I made a library called [pychbase](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pychbase) that uses the MapR C api called `libhbase` to connect to `maprdb`.

The goal is to track the `HappyBase` API as best as possible. Unfortunately libhbase doesn't provide all the same features that HappyBase does, so I'm raising `NotImplementedError` when it happens.

Check the Readme out for details on how to install it and let me know if you need any assistance.

Here is the github [repo](https://github.com/mkmoisen/pychbase/blob/master/pychbase/__init__.py).